# C++ File Input/Output Outputting Numbers Instead of Chars

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have created a program that randomly assigns roles(jobs) to members of a certain house using file input / output.. It builds successfully, but when using cout and I actually see the results, I can see why the program is not working.

Here is the snippet of code I believe something is wrong with :

```
  std::string foo = std::string("Preferences/") + std::to_string(members[random]) + "-Preferences";
  cout << foo << endl;
```

And here is the members[random] array, it is randomly selecting members from this array and reviewing their available times and  assigning them jobs based on their Preference input file.

```
unsigned const char members[22] = 
{   'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v'  };
```

I have created a random number picker that goes through 0-21 and assigns the value it creates to variable random. So, in essence, it is members[random] and completely random.

Here is the output I get in my terminal.

```
Preferences/116-Preferences
```

But I set the output to do Preferences/ member[random] -Preferences.
It is accessing a number and not my array chars.

I created a cout << members[random]; right below it, and every time I run the program, I get

```
  Preferences/107-Preferences   <---- A random number every time

  k                   <---- random letter every time.
```

So I know it must be accessing my random functions, but assigned it to numbers! How do I fix this so my proper output can be :

```
 Preferences/t-Preferences
```

Please help me, and thanks!

Comment: `std::to_string` doesn't take a character as an input.  Just add the character to the string.

Comment: I need a random output though. I NEED it to access members[random]. Is there an std::to_char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `::std::to_string(char)`, only (among less close) `::std::to_string(int)`. So your character is actually converted to its numerical representation and you get your unwanted result.

Try instead

```cpp
std::string foo("Preferences/");
foo = foo.append(1, members[random]).append("-Preferences");
```

Variant using string streams:

```cpp
ostringstream oss;
oss << "Preferences/" << members[random] << "-Preferences";
// get your string via:
oss.str();
```

Comment: Why thank you! It works but it doesn't.
While your chars work and everything, every some time it outputs a char that is not exactly correct.
For example, sometimes instead of a normal y in Preferences/y-Preferences I get a strange y with a tilde. Or an O with a horizontal colon. or a u with a line over it. Help!

Comment: Those strange chars only happened a few times, then I edited out some code like couts and others, and they seemingly stopped. 

Thanks for the help, and keep it up!

Comment: Strange... Seems as if there was some encoding issue. But as your members all were ascii characters only, they should have been fine, even if your file was encoded in utf8, latin-1 (iso 8859-1), windows-cp<whatever> or most (but not all) others (and in this domain, no matter if using char or unsigned char - although Sam V. is right, simply `char` is sufficient...)

Answer (score 3):

> "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up
>   the drain" - Scotty, Star Trek III

Declaring `members` to be `unsigned char`s does not accomplish anything useful. A simple `char` will suffice. `std::string` already implements an overloaded `+` operator that takes a `char` parameter, so it's much easier than you thought it would be:

```
const char members[22] = {
   'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v'  };

// ...

std::string foo = std::string("Preferences/") + members[random]
                  + "-Preferences";
```

Comment: Compiles without any issues. Any errors must come as a result of your code which you did not include in your question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik operator+(): got me, better than `append`... +1